# how to read a text file in R, having only the file's FULL PATH name ,I have as an info

Tags: r, text, path, directory

I have several text file scattered in folders, sub-folders.
I have a scenario where I get a .CSV file which has one of its column as "PATH" 
 containing the FULL PATH name of Text file one by one under that column for example:`-             PATH (column1)
                               ---------------------------------
                               (row)1.c:\desktop....\wd\abc.txt 
                               (row)2.c:\desktop....\bv\qwe.txt 
                               (row)3.c:\desktop....\qp\mno.txt`

like this...
now my question is there any function in R, where I don't have to set the working directory for loading that text file, as I have said the text file are all in different location and it will be hard for me to set working dirextory every-time I  want to load file one by one. any help is appreciated. :)

Comment: Do you want to get content of every file listed in your `PATH` column ?

Comment: yes @ParthChaudhary.

Comment: I think the only way to do this is to decompose the FULLPATH into (directoryPATH and filenamePATH) i.e ("c:\desktop....\qp\mno.txt"------> "c:\desktop....\qp\" +"mno.txt" ).....but thats the thing I dont know

Comment: you can run a loop over `PATH` column and use `readChar` as below

Comment: `readChar("D:/dummy/a.txt", file.info("D:/dummy/a.txt")$size)`

Comment: thanks @ParthChaudhary its works :)